# htmlentities and json_encode, do I need to use htmlentities if using json_encode which escapes data?

Tags: php, jquery, json

htmlentities and json_encode, do I need to use htmlentities if using json_encode which escapes data?

is this enough - json_encode escapes data

```
    echo json_encode( $items );
```

or do this use htmlentities to escape data:

```
    foreach ( $data as $d ) {

        $items[] = htmlentities( $d );

    }

    echo json_encode( $items );
```

client-side:  JQuery ajax :

```
    $('#textbox').attr( 'value', variable );
```

Comment: Why not use a framework that abstracts away these kinds of concerns? Symfony is a decent one: http://symfony.com/

Comment: [The Great Escapism (Or: What You Need To Know To Work With Text Within Text)](http://kunststube.net/escapism/)

Comment: I intend to use and learn a framework in the future, but first I need to learn php well enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you should not need to use `htmlentities()`.

I'm assuming you're using this in the context of an ajax handler? If so, you're biggest concern will be what exactly your calling script is expecting back. If you're handling the JSON response appropriately, there is no need to do anything besides `json_encode()`.